# No drag and drop events fired in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, dom-events

I'm stuck with a problem in IE11.

The drag and drop events are not triggered in IE11.
First I thought it has something to do with the IE settings (security>Allow drag drop).

I use jQuery, but it doesn't work with plain JavaScript as well.

I broke it down to the following piece of code:

```
    <script>
       document.addEventListener('dragenter', function (event) {
                alert("Dragenter");

            });
    </script>
```

When I drag a file from my desktop into the browser, the alert appears.
It works fine with Chrome, Edge, Firefox, but not with IE.

Unfortunately it still doesn’t work in my current project. Even the simple js snippet.
Any Ideas?

I added my site to the trusted sites, enabled ActiveX, Enabled all other scripting settings, but it looks still like the Browser is blocking drag and drop actions for my site.

Comment: This is only a Problem, if i host it on my loacal IIS!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on my side and the alert appears successfully.
[image: the running result]

I suggest that you could check the Drag and Drop feature in your IE.

1. Go to Internet Options
2. Go to Security tab
3. Click on Custom level
4. Search for Drag and Drop settings and Click on Enables
5. Click Ok

Comment: Thank you very much, for your reply. This works as well for me, if i ut the code into a html file. But it doesn't work, if i host it locally on my IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The problem was, that i started my IE as an administrator (from Visual Studio).

It is not possible , to move files from your local users desktop, to an IE in administrator-mode.